# Javascript: Invalid left-hand side in assignment [Read all the others]

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to create a script that goes through a form and populates all fields with test text.

The idea is that it goes through the loop once for each date variable in a month, that have the naming convention DateJan1, DateFeb28, etc, and place the word "test" in the box. Below is my code:

```
var i;
for(i = 1; i < 31; i++){
    var nDate = "DateJan" + i;
    document.getElementById('FIELD_'+ (FieldIDs[nDate]).value = "test";
}
```

However, I keep getting the Invalid left-hand side error with the line:

```
document.getElementById('FIELD_'+ (FieldIDs[nDate]).value = "test";
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: you are missing a `)`

Comment: Good Eye @PatrickEvans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('FIELD_'+ (FieldIDs[nDate]).value = "test";
```

This statement is missing a `)`.
I'm assuming you are trying to achieve the following:

```
document.getElementById('FIELD_'+ (FieldIDs[nDate])).value = "test";
```

Comment: or `document.getElementById('FIELD_'+ FieldIDs[nDate]).value = "test";`

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be

```
document.getElementById('FIELD_'+ (FieldIDs[nDate])).value = "test";
```

I think you forgot a closing bracket `)`